# rstudio: error while loading shared libraries

Tags: rstudio, shared-libraries, archlinux

After I upgrade my (arch linux) system I get de following error when I try to open Rstudio:

```
rstudio: error while loading shared libraries: 
libboost_date_time.so.1.66.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

After looking at `usr/lib` directory I found that the new library is `libboost_date_time.so.1.67.0`. How can I update the library path to the new file?

Reinstalling rstudio is not an option right now because I get another error that I posted in other topic.